# Configuring IIS to pass POST data through 301 redirect

Tags: http, iis, redirect, iis-7

I am currently working on a site hosted on IIS 7 for a client, and the site is configured to redirect any naked domain requests to redirect to the 'www' subdomain. However, this is causing a problem with some of the forms on the site, which point to the naked domain. When the form is submitted, it forwards to the correct page on the 'www'subdomain, but the POST parameters are lost - the page on the 'www' subdomain is requested with an HTTP GET request regardless of the request type of the original request.

I am very unfamiliar with IIS and its configuration, so I imagine that this is something simple to fix, but how can I ensure that POST requests are preserved over a 301 redirect on IIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you post via 301 the post data will be removed. You need create eq php script that re-parse data and send again

```
/* FOR test */

$_POST['value'] = 123;
$_POST['key']  = 888;
# Online $_POST check
$_GET['redirect'] = 'https://posttestserver.com/post.php'; 
/* END: FOR test */


if( filter_var($_GET['redirect'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) {

    if ( is_array($_POST) ) :

        echo '<form method="post" action="'. $_GET['redirect'] .'" name="f">';

        foreach($_POST as $i => $v){
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="'. $i .'" value="'. $v .'">';
        }

        echo '</form> <script> document.f.submit(); </script>';

    else : // IF _GET

        $tmp = $_GET['redirect'];
        unset($_GET['redirect']);
        $ur = http_build_query($_GET);
        header("Location: " . $tmp . '?' . $ur);
    endif;
}
```